# Symbol cannot be resolved when entered as a parameter in constructor

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on a coding task as part of one of my labs for a University paper and stuck on setting up my constructor and a couple of booleans that are to pull an age variable from the constructor without using another data field (age), in the class. Can anyone shed any light on why I can't resolve these symbols (age) in my booleans, even though age is a parameter in the constructor?

UML Diagram:

- name: string
- child: boolean
- student: boolean

---

- Customer(nameIn:String, age:int, studentIn:boolean)
- getName(): String
- isChild(): boolean
- isStudent(): boolean

and here is my code so far:

```
public class Customer {
    /**Data Field declarations */
    String name;
    boolean child;
    boolean student;
    boolean booked;




    /** Contstructor for the customer
    * @param nameIn, age and is student
    */
    public Customer (String nameIn, int age, boolean studentIn) {

        this.name = nameIn;
        this.student = studentIn;
    } //end method

    /**Accessor method to get name of customer */
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }//end method

    /**Boolean test method to check if child */
    private boolean isChild() {
        if (age <= 5 && age >= 17)
            return child;
    }//end method

    /**Boolean test method to check if student */
    private boolean isStudent() {
        if (age <= 16 && age >= 18)
            return student;
    }//end method
}
```

Please help! Been stuck on this for a few hours now!

Comment: I don't see an `age` field declared anywhere. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hey Logan, as part of the task, we aren't allowed any more class data fields than what's already listed (we have to work from the above UML diagram).

Comment: Well the issue is that you can’t refer to `age` in any of your methods if it isn’t a field or parameter. The only place I see it is in your constructor. Does it give any more instructions?

Comment: The task might be to set `child` depending on `age`.

Comment: well one thing is your both if conditions on age will always be false and nothing will be returned when you will call both the methods

Comment: What are the conditions to be child and student? age <= 5 && age >= 17 doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: A child is defined as between 5 and 16 years old (inclusive)

Comment: @SamMatthews Do you set if it's a student in the constructor (studentIn) or with the age parameter? or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your booleans in the constructor (i.e with a method to evaluate age) and then use public method to access those attributes.

### Customer:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private boolean child, student;

    public Customer(String nameIn, int age, boolean studentIn) {

        this.name = nameIn;
        this.student = studentIn;
        this.child = isChild(age);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private boolean isChild(int age) {
        return (age >= 5 && age <= 16);
    }

    public boolean isStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public boolean isChild() {
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [name=" + name + ", child=" + child + ", student=" + student + "]";
    }

}
```

### MainP:

```
public class MainP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer c1 = new Customer("c1", 5, true);

        System.out.println(c1.getName() + " " + c1.isChild() + " " + c1.isStudent());

        Customer c2 = new Customer("c2", 50, false);

        System.out.println(c2.getName() + " " + c2.isChild() + " " + c2.isStudent());

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
c1 true true
c2 false false
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up with!! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the Testing for wether the Customer with the given age is a child within the constructor. If it is the set child to true, otherwise to false. So the same for student.
Then you can rewrite the isChild() and isStudent() function so that it returns the attribute value of the class.

Comment: As stated by the questioner, no more fields can be added. Otherwise, this would be a valid approach.

Comment: Hey Nick, the listed class attributes are all we are allowed to work with. age has to be dealt with outside of the class data fields. Which is why I'm stuck!

Comment: Thanks Nick! So my constructor and isChild() would look like this?:
/** Contstructor for the customer
     * @param nameIn, age and is student
     */
    public Customer (String nameIn, int age, boolean studentIn) {

        this.name = nameIn;
        this.student = studentIn;

        if (age >= 5 && age <= 16)
            child = true;
    } //end method

    /**Boolean test method to check if child */
    private boolean isChild() {
            return child;
    }//end method

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

In your `isChild()` and `isStudent()` methods, you don't pass any age parameter. You should pass an `int age` parameter in both of those methods, and set the values of the booleans to `child = isChild(age)` and `student = isStudent(age)`. It should in the end look like the hastebin here: https://hastebin.com/nowopokuyu.java . Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! As per the UML diagram, we also can't pass parameters to the isChild() or isStudent methods() , which would make this a lot easier if we could! :(

Comment: Your isChild(age) method won't compile!

Comment: What is the task at hand in the first place?

Comment: @Rcordoval, yes it will, check the hastebin.

Comment: You have to return something even if the if don't enter @Mr_Rhetorical

Comment: @Rcordoval, you're right... I didn't see that the return statement is only for if it is a child.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can’t resolve the `age` variable in your Boolean methods is that `age` is only accessible within the constructor.

Why not move your conditional logic and set the values of `child` and `student` within the constructor and provide simple getters as you’ve done with `name`?

There’s also an issue with your conditions - you’ve mixed up your `<=` and `>=` in such a way that those conditions can never evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Just fixed up my boolean! There's a statement in the requirements that makes me think the boolean needs to be outside of the constructor: "The class should have accessors for these three data fields. Rather than prefix the boolean's accessor method with get, use is. The advantage of this will be easier-to-read if statements later on"

Comment: `is` is a common prefix for Boolean getters. It lets you write readable code such as `if (customer.isChild()) { ... }` which is how I would interpret that quote (and not as a constraint against setting the field values within the constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
private boolean isChild() {
    if (age <= 5 && age >= 17)
        return child;
}
```

Not all paths return a value. You must set the variables for `child` and `student` in the constructor. I would change it to be like so in this hastebin, so long as you can use `isChild` as an accessor: https://hastebin.com/oqiqobayuw.java

edit: also the `>=` and `<=` are flipped for each of the comparisons.